# calculate hours/minutes between two times in dart

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

I want to get/calculate hours and minutes between two times in dart.
Example: if start_time is 17:30 and end_time is 09:00 (day after) it should return total: 15 hours 30 minutes

My code:

```
check_two_times_is_before(String start_time, String end_time){
    var format = DateFormat("HH:mm");
    var start = format.parse(start_time);
    var end = format.parse(end_time);

    if(start.isAfter(end)) {
     // do something here
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `difference` method on `DateTime` class.

```dart
check_two_times_is_before(String start_time, String end_time){
    var format = DateFormat("HH:mm");
    var start = format.parse(start_time);
    var end = format.parse(end_time);

    if(start.isAfter(end)) {
       end = end.add(Duration(days: 1));
       Duration diff = end.difference(start);
       final hours = diff.inHours;
       final minutes = diff.inMinutes % 60;
       print('$hours hours $minutes minutes');
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is not correct because it return 8 hours 510 minutes when you test start_time is 17:30 and end_time is 09:00 it should return total: 15 hours 30 minutes

Comment: Yeah you are right. I edited my solution to solve both problems. Can you check again? Basically, if start is after end, just add 1 day to end duration, so you can get desired difference.

Comment: The new edit return 8 hours 30 minutes it should return : 15 hours 30 minutes

Comment: While copy pasting, I missed a line. I hope this will be the final edit :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with Duration class

```
Duration duration = end.difference(start).abs();
final hours = duration.inHours;
final minutes = duration.inMinutes % 60;
print('$hours hours $minutes minutes');
```

Comment: The minutes calculation could be simply `minutes = duration.inMinutes % 60;`.

Comment: Your solution return: -8 hours 30 minutes  when you test start_time is 17:30 and end_time is 09:00 it should return total: 15 hours 30 minutes

Comment: @blue492 adding the `abs()` function will resolve the problem. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty old but here is another solution which might help someone.

```
Duration duration = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestmap).difference(DateTime.now()).abs();
final days = duration.inDays;
final hours = duration.inHours - (days * 24);
final minutes = duration.inMinutes - (days * 24 * 60) - (hours * 60);
final seconds = duration.inSeconds - (days * 24 * 60 * 60) - (hours * 60 * 60) - (minutes * 60);
```

Nothing to explain here really. We're just using basic algebra. We're getting the total number of milliseconds between the two timestamps and working that down to days, hours, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 0):

the solution should be like this, :

```
  var format = DateFormat("HH:mm");
  var start = format.parse("08:50");
  var end = format.parse("08:48");

  if (start.isAfter(end)) {
    end = end.add(Duration(days: 0));
    Duration diff = end.difference(start).abs();
    final hours = diff.inHours;
    final minutes = diff.inMinutes % 60;
    print('$hours hours $minutes minutes');
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).